# Transparent Flash Embed Code; Trouble Substituting My Own Content?

Tags: html, flash, web, embed, dreamweaver

I'm trying to put transparent video on a website for work (I know how most of you will probably feel about this, but this is beyond my control.)

Here is the code I got from an example page:

```
<div id="video" style="z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; right: 5px; bottom: 0px; display: block;"><object align="center" width="146" height="386" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://hosting.modeltoweb.com/washerwizardsamber/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" style="height:386px;"><param name="scale" value="noscale"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="salign" value="tl"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000"><param name="showvolume" value="0"><param name="flashvars" value="streamName=http://hosting.modeltoweb.com/washerwizardsamber/washerwizardsamber&amp;skinName=http://hosting.modeltoweb.com/washerwizardsamber/Clear_Skin_1&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;autoPlay=true"></object></div>
```

You can add this code in an HTML and it will play the file if you wish to see what I'm talking about.

It seems like no matter what I do, as soon as I start replacing the streamName info, it never wants to load anything. I've created an .flv that is the exact same size as the file being used.